# In Sculpt can grab-tool push along normals?

Tags: normals, sculpting

I just found out in ZBrush when sculpting with the grab tool, they can press Alt and it will push along the normals, and wondered if blender could do anything like this?

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out.  You press control while dragging.